# How to snap this UV map's corner to the 2D cursor?

Tags: uv

This is my UV map:

[image: UV map]

And I am looking for a precise way to snap left bottom vertex to the 2D cursor location, something like this:

[image: 2nd UV]

When I try to do it with CTRL + move, it's not precise, but my texturing guy requires me to do it so.

Also, I can't use image constrains because when I try to enable it, my unwrap is broken.

Smart UV project may be useful in this specific case, but I'm gonna soon unwrap models, where Smart UV unwrap is gonna be... a bad idea.

Thanks for help in advantage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the <kbd>N</kbd> *Numbers Panel* to see the vertex coordinates, then:

1. To align the left side to the left border (to move the left edge to x=0), select the leftmost vertex, hover over its x coordinate, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, then  <kbd>A</kbd> select everything, <kbd>G</kbd> move <kbd>X</kbd> locked to X axis, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> paste the offset, <kbd>-</kbd> change the sign and <kbd>Enter</kbd> confirm.
2. To align the bottom side to the bottom border, do the same as above but with bottom-most vertex and Y coordinate/axis.

[image]

3. If your cursor is not in the bottom left, open the *View* tab in the *Numbers Panel* move everything an arbitrary (doesn't matter where) distance, and copy-paste the 3D cursors coordinates to the *Move* panel coordinates:

[image]